# Spring security circular bean dependency error

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security

When setting up spring security `method authentication` with a custom access decision manager, I get a circular bean dependency error that aborts server startup.

The custom access decision manager reads security reference data from a database, using services that are also used elsewhere in the application and are themselves secured:

I am using spring security `3.0.5`, this is the main error message (see full stacktrace bellow):

> Error creating bean with name 'securityReferenceDataService': Bean
>   with name 'securityReferenceDataService' has been injected into other
>   beans [myAccessDecisionManager] in its raw version as part of a
>   circular reference, but has eventually been wrapped.

This is the spring configuration for the  `global-security-method` element and the security reference data service:

```
<bean id="myAccessDecisionManager" class="sample.mvc.root.context.services.MyAccessDecisionManager">
    <property name="securityReferenceDataService" ref="securityReferenceDataService"/>
</bean>

<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" 
jsr250-annotations="enabled" access-decision-manager-ref="myAccessDecisionManager" />
```

This is the simplified code for the security reference data service:

```
public class SecurityReferenceDataDao {

    @Secured(value = "ADMIN")
    public List<SecurityReferenceData> loadSecurityReferenceData() {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Full stack trace:**

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityReferenceDataService': Bean with name 'securityReferenceDataService' has been injected into other beans [myAccessDecisionManager] in its raw version as part of a circular reference, but has eventually been wrapped. This means that said other beans do not use the final version of the bean. This is often the result of over-eager type matching - consider using 'getBeanNamesOfType' with the 'allowEagerInit' flag turned off, for example.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:549)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.doStart(Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.java:115)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginServer.start(Jetty6PluginServer.java:132)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:454)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:396)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6RunWar.execute(Jetty6RunWar.java:67)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:46)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the reference data service used by the custom access decision manager is itself secured with `@Secured`.

This causes a situation where to create the access decision manager, we need to wrap it in a security proxy that needs the access decision manager, that needs the security reference data service, that needs to be wrapped in a proxy linked to the access decision manager, ... etc.

The way this works is that the `global-method-security` element (in non aspectJ mode) causes spring security to register a  security advisor `MethodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor`, that will get applied to any bean containing at least one `@Secured` annotation.

To break the circular injection problem, the solution is to pass to the custom access decision manager a non-secured version of the reference data service, to which the security aspect is not applied. These are two ways to do this:

**Using spring security run-as-manager-ref solution:**

One way is to use spring security 3.1 has a [Run-As](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/83133-run-as-configuration) mechanism to have the method security access decision manager run with a given role instead of the roles of the current user, using property run-as-manager-ref of `global-method-security`.

**Using a inner bean:**

In an application where aspects are applied using the most common weaving mechanisms (JDK or CGLIB proxies), this can also be solved with an inner bean:

```
<bean id="myAccessDecisionManager" class="sample.mvc.root.context.services.MyAccessDecisionManager">
    <property name="securityReferenceDataService">
        <bean  class="sample.mvc.root.context.services.SecurityReferenceDataDao"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

***Note: This would not work if using load-time or compile-time weaving***